# For a graph $G$ find the minimal $t$ such $G(t)=(V,E(t))$ is connected

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a connected and directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with positive weights on the edges. for every $t>0$ we define $E(t)$ to be the group of edges with weight lower or equal than $t$. I need to find an efficient algorithm which computes the minimal $t$ such that $G(t)=(V,E(t))$ is connected.

I can sort all the edges with $|E|\log|E|$ complexity and try to take edges out of the graph from the heaviest to the easiet one, and to check with DFS if it is still connected, but its not effiecnt enough,

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is "efficient enough" for you? What do you want the algorithm for, or is it an exercise?

Comment: It's an exercise. Efficient enough is the quickest you can come up with, and of course not the trivial solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Compute a [minimum bottleneck spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Minimum_bottleneck_spanning_tree) of the graph. (Actually just compute a minimum spanning tree, as a minimum spanning tree is a minimum bottleneck tree.)
2. Determine the maximum edge weight from MBST, this will be your $t$.
3. Remove all edges whose weight is higher.

This can be done in linear time in the sum of the number of nodes and edges (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)).

Comment: I'm sorry, we didn't learn about the minimum bottleneck tree in class. I am afraid I can't use it.

Comment: If you read the answer more carefully, you will realise that you can use minimum spanning trees. You just need to prove the the maximum edge in the MST is minimal.

Comment: You right. I understand the answer. Thanks a lot Dave.

Comment: How come it's linear? Finding MST is not linear.

Comment: Oops. Linear in the number of nodes plus edges (if weights are integers).

Comment: It's whether Kruskal with $O(|E|log|V|)$ or Prim with $O(|E|+|V|log|V|)$.